# Use PHP preg_replace to remove ? only where it is not following by a "=" sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am after (if possible), a reg expression which will only replace questions marks "?" with "'" where it is not followed by the "=" symbol in my string?

e.g. this is something?, but this will remain?=forever

should end up as:

this is something', but this will remain?=forever

Thanks

Mu

Comment: This is called a [lookahead](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

Comment: Specifically, you want the expression to match all ?s that are *not* followed by an equals sign. So you want *negative* lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple using a negative lookahead: Use

```
\?(?!=)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check this.. Simple one without regex ( I don't know regex :( )...:p

```
$string = "this is something?, but this will remain?=forever";
$my_secret_replace = "THISISANYTHINGWHICHWILLNOTINSTRING_OR_ANYRANDOMNUMBER";



$temp_string = str_replace("?=",$my_secret_replace,$string);
$temp_string = str_replace("?","'",$temp_string);
$final_string = str_replace($my_secret_replace,"?=",$temp_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "String contains ? and ?= contains too?=?";
echo preg_replace("/\?([^=]|$)/", "'\\1", $string);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, and the info about using negative lookaheads